# Job title changes after you submit a message

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The job title in the Messaging module is changing after the user submits a reply to the message thread. See below:

BEFORE

[image: BEFORE]

AFTER

[image: AFTER]

Comment: Investigating...

Comment: I can't repro just yet, but we're digging a little deeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be fixed.

We had recently broken some SQL that would pull the data for that message thread. It was accidentally grabbing the data for all of your message threads, and would thus accidentally use the title from a different message (your first one).

Thanks for the bug report.